# Is it a good design to bind to visibility in viewmodel

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Recently myself and my collegue are discussing regarding view binding to visibility property which is in a viewModel.

In one of our project, in order to make a control visible / collapse my colleague binded to a visibility property and the viewModel will set the property to Visibility.Visible / Visibility.Collapse when necessary.

It works, but I want to know is it a good design.

As I am thinking , if the viewModel is setting the property to Visible / collapse, then viewModel knows what view is doing, instead  it should contain a bool property and the view should binded to a bool property and use a converter to decide whether to make the element visible / collapse. In which case viewmodel knows nothing about the view .

Example :
Showing a TextBlock( Team name ) if the user belongs to a team

```
private bool _isUserBelongsToTeam;
public bool IsUserBelongsToTeam
{
   get { return _isUserBelongsToTeam; }
   set { _isUserBelongsToTeam = value; NotifyPropertyChange("IsUserBelongsToTeam"); }
}

XAML: 
<TextBlock Text= "Team name" Visibility= "{Binding IsUserBelongsToTeam, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}" />

private bool _isTeamVisible;
public bool IsTeamVisible
{
   get { return _isTeamVisible; }
   set { _isTeamVisible= value; NotifyPropertyChange("IsTeamVisible"); }
}

XAML: 
<TextBlock Text= "Team name" Visibility= "{Binding IsTeamVisible}" />
```

which way is better to implement?

Comment: Please remember to upvote helpful answers :) https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a matter of taste really. I personally prefer the converter approach in most cases. The benefit of defining the view model property as a `bool` is that it has no dependency upon any view related type.

This is especially important if you share (or intend to share) your view models between several different types of client applications.

But as far as MVVM is concerned, you don't really break the pattern by adding a `Visibility` property to the view model class. Also, this might actually be better than using a converter for performance reasons if you intend to display a lot of view model instances in an `ItemsControl`.

Comment: Thank you mm8. This clarifies me. if it is one view and one viewModel it is good to have Visibility, many views and one viewModel good to have bool..

Comment: Yes, or rather, if you intend to create a lot of view model objects and bind to these, you may don't want to use a converter.

Answer (score 3):

1. Remember that you spend more time reading the code, then writing. Hence 'IsTeamMember' is a better name then 'IsTeamVisible'. And IsUserBelongsToTeam is terrible (ungrammatical) :)
2. I've just rewrote a whole module in our WPF application. I didn't use a single 'IsXYZVisible' property. I'm using ContentPresenter with DataTemplates, and I null the Content property in ContentPresenter, when I don't want to display the content. This way I have: simpler xaml, simpler and smaller view models, code better reflects the view (if, during debugging, I see that XYZ sub-viewModel property is null, then I know it's not being rendered, and I don't have to search for IsXYZVisible or similar properties), unit tests are simpler.